# I want to refresh Telerik kendoMobileListView on button click

Tags: telerik, kendo-mobile, kendo-listview, telerik-appbuilder

Actually I have a refresh button after listview, I want to refresh kendoMobileListView every time when user click on that button.. How can I refresh the kendo list?

```
<ul id="cart-products" data-role="listview" data-pull-to-refresh="true" data-messages='{ "refreshTemplate": "Refreshing!" }'  data-source="CartData" data-template="cart-template"></ul>
```

Comment: have you tried `$("#listView").data("kendoMobileListView").refresh()`

Comment: yes !! it is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is working I am using this

```
$(document).on("click", ".remove-product", function () {
    $("#cart-products").data("kendoMobileListView").dataSource.read();
    $("#cart-products").data("kendoMobileListView").refresh();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using:

```
var CartData = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {        
        read: function(options) {
            <your code>
        }
    }
});
```

for your data-source. You can use `CartData.read()` on your click button.